# Stopping gradient flow for a multiple headed Pytorch module

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a multiple headed model in Pytorch, similar to this one:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
         super(Net, self).__init__()
    
         self.backbone = Backbone()
         self.proxyModule = ProxyModule()

    def forward(self, x):
         backbone_output = self.backbone(x)
         proxy_target = transform_to_targets(backbone_output)
         proxy_output = self.proxyModule(backbone_output)
         return backbone_output, proxy_target, proxy_output 

net = Net()
x,y = get_some_data()
backbone_output, proxy_target, proxy_output = net(x)
backbone_loss = Loss(backbone_output, y)
proxy_loss = Loss(proxy_output, proxy_target)
total_loss = backbone_loss + proxy_loss
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Basically, I want to update the backbone model, and the proxy model via the same loss. However, I do not want that Backbone module gets updated via the operation `proxy_target = transform_to_targets(backbone_output)`. The purpose in there is only to generate output variables for the proxyModule. That is similar to a Q-learning scenario, actually.

I have the following modification in mind but I am not sure if that would work as I expect:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
         super(Net, self).__init__()
    
         self.backbone = Backbone()
         self.proxyModule = ProxyModule()

    def forward(self, x):
         backbone_output = self.backbone(x)

         with torch.set_grad_enabled(False):
              proxy_target = transform_to_targets(backbone_output)

         proxy_output = self.proxyModule(backbone_output)
         return backbone_output, proxy_target, proxy_output 

net = Net()
x,y = get_some_data()

optimizer.zero_grad()
with torch.set_grad_enabled(True):
    backbone_output, proxy_target, proxy_output = net(x)
    backbone_loss = Loss(backbone_output, y)
    proxy_loss = Loss(proxy_output, proxy_target)
    total_loss = backbone_loss + proxy_loss
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

The difference is now I have put the line `proxy_target = transform_to_targets(backbone_output)` into the context manager where I set the gradient calculation to false. Lately the Autograd mechanism in Pytorch became more complex, so I cannot be sure if this would provide the intended effect.

Comment: How is `transform_to_targets` defined?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_grad_enabled.html) gives clear examples that this achieves the effect that you want. I would assume that the maintainers are capable of writing proper test cases to cover this.

And quoting from [this answer from albanD](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-compute-gradients-and-do-back-propagation-by-a-skipping-way/83531/2):

> Yes doing with torch.no_grad() will prevent gradient from flowing back all the way to moduleA.

where moduleA produces output that is processed by moduleB (which is executed within `no_grad`).

Alternatively: use `.detach()` on `proxy_target`. That detaches the tensor from the computation graph and no gradient can flow back. But I'm assuming using `no_grad` is cheaper since the computational graph will not be stored at all in this case.

**NOTE:** Setting `requires_grad` to `False` manually on an intermediate module [will let the gradients pass to earlier modules still](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-will-happen-if-i-set-requires-grad-false/54877). This is different to using `no_grad` and then checking if the output tensor has `requires_grad` set to `True`.

---

But if you still don't feel comfortable then do a little test:

1. Check if `proxy_target.requires_grad` is `False`
2. Return only `proxy_target` and create the rest in the forward function as new tensors (they will 100% not have any impact on the gradient). Store the full model weights before and after your pipeline, run for one iteration and check if there are any differences in the weights.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. In the ``transform_to_targets`` I do lots of copying into empty tensors already from the backbone outputs to create targets. ``proxy_target.requires_grad`` returns False already even without the context manager. In that case it wont propagate gradients back, is that right?

Comment: I provided some more details in my answer. I'm not sure if copying into empty tensors prevents gradients from being copied. Depends on how you do this. `proxy_target.requires_grad=False` is correct but it only shows that `no_grad` (equiv. to `set_grad_enabled(False)`) worked correctly. Like stated in my answer, if you check `requires_grad` on an intermediate layer (!), the gradients might still get propagates to earlier layers (if they require a grad).